# Привязка значения из ViewModel ко всем элементам ListBox MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

У меня есть окно, в нем есть combobox в котором я выбираю размер шрифта для текста в окне.

Я хочу привязать FontSize к значению из viewModel. TextBlock'и меняют размер шрифта, а элементы ListBox'a нет.

Класс modelView:

```
public class modelVeiw : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    const int F1big = 20;
    const int F1mid = F1big - 4;
    const int F1small = F1big - 8;

    const int F2big = 18;
    const int F2mid = F2big - 4;
    const int F2small = F2big - 8;

    const int F3big = 16;
    const int F3mid = F3big - 4;
    const int F3small = F3big - 8;

    public ObservableCollection<string> comboItems { get; set; }

    private string selectedbox;
    public string SelectedBox
    {
        get { return selectedbox; }
        set
        {
            selectedbox = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedBox");
        }
    }


    #region MyRegion
    private int big;
    public int Big
    {
        get { return big; }
        set
        {
            big = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Big");
        }
    }

    private int med;
    public int Med
    {
        get { return med; }
        set
        {
            med = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Med");
        }
    }

    private int small;
    public int Small
    {
        get { return small; }
        set
        {
            small = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Small");
        }
    }

    private List<Person> llist;
    public List<Person> LList
    {
        get { return llist; }
        set
        {
            llist = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LList");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private RelayCommand selectedCommand;
    public RelayCommand SelectedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedCommand ??
              (selectedCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
              {
                  string sel = obj as String;
                  if (sel != null)
                  {
                      if (sel == "Большой шрифт")
                      {
                          Big = F1big;
                          Med = F1mid;
                          Small = F1small;
                      }
                      else if (sel == "Средний шрифт")
                      {
                          Big = F2big;
                          Med = F2mid;
                          Small = F2small;
                      }
                      else if (sel == "Маленький шрифт")
                      {
                          Big = F3big;
                          Med = F3mid;
                          Small = F3small;
                      }
                  }
              },
             (obj) => true));
        }
    }

    public modelVeiw()
    {
        comboItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        comboItems.Add("Большой шрифт");
        comboItems.Add("Средний шрифт");
        comboItems.Add("Маленький шрифт");
        SelectedBox = comboItems[0];
        Big = F1big;
        Med = F1mid;
        Small = F1small;

        LList = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person {Name = "Иван", Lastname ="Иванов" , Age =10 },
            new Person {Name = "Петр", Lastname ="Петров" , Age =15 },
            new Person {Name = "Артем", Lastname ="Артемов" , Age =20 }
        };

    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Xaml-разметка

```
<Window x:Class="Font_size.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Font_size"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox Name="combobox" ItemsSource="{Binding comboItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBox}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedBox}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ComboBox>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Margin ="5" Text="Большой" FontSize="{Binding Big}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Margin ="5" Text="Средний" FontSize="{Binding Med}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Margin ="5" Text="Маленький" FontSize="{Binding Small}"></TextBlock>

        <ListBox Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding LList}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Height="auto">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="{Binding Big}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Lastname}" FontSize="{Binding Med}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age} FontSize="{Binding Small}""></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

[image: Скриншот программы]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вашего `ListBox.Item` другой дата контекст - типа `Person`. Чтобы привязаться к дата контексту `Window`, вы должны это явно указать на всех привязках:

```
<Window x:Name="ThisView"
        ...>
    <StackPanel>
    ...
        <ListBox Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding LList}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Height="auto">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                            FontSize="{Binding DataContext.Big, ElementName=ThisView}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Lastname}"
                            FontSize="{Binding DataContext.Med, ElementName=ThisView}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"
                            FontSize="{Binding DataContext.Small, ElementName=ThisView}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Либо можно находить вьюху с помощью `RelativeSource` по требуемому типу (в нашем случае это `Window`), но лично я стараюсь этого избегать:

```
{Binding DataContext.Small, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}
```